# PHP page reloading insted of submitting to server

Tags: php

I would need a fresh pair of eyes. I don't see my error. I created a series of forms to verify users information. My first and second work great, but when I get to my third form it keeps reloading the same page.

PHP

```
<?php
```

My session started on my login form. The serie of forms is to update the informatio I have on the users. So I requested some info for validation on my first form. On the second I asked if their unit is rented. On the third I

```
    session_start();
```

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }
```

Setup my connection in PDO

```
    require_once "config.php";
```

Set my variables. I will add the error blocks to my form later on. I

```
    $contactid = $_SESSION["contactid"];
    $address = $streetNum = $street = $city = $country = $zip = $unit = $province = "";
    $streetNum_err = $street_err = $city_err = $country_err = $zip_err = $unit_err = $province_err = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        if(empty(trim($_POST["streetnumber"]))){
            $streetNum_err = "Must enter street number!";
        }else{
            $streetNum = trim($_POST["streetnumber"]);
        }

        if(empty(trim($_POST["street"]))){
            $street_err = "Must enter street name !";
        }else{
            $street = trim($_POST["street"]);
        }

        if(empty(trim($_POST["city"]))){
            $city_err = "Must enter city !";
        }else{
            $city = trim($_POST["city"]);
        }

        if(empty(trim($_POST["country"]))){
            $country_err = "Must select a country !";
        }else{
            $country = trim($_POST["country"]);
        }

        if(empty(trim($_POST["zip"]))){
            $zip_err = "Must enter Zip/Postal code !";
        }else{
            $zip = trim($_POST["zip"]);
        }

        $unit = trim($_POST["unit"]);

        if(empty(trim($_POST["province"]))){
            $province_err = "Must enter State/Province !";
        }else{
            $province = trim($_POST["province"]);
        }
```

I think my errors starts here. I want to store all the above as one string.

```
        $address =  $streetNum . " " . $street . ", " . $unit . ", " .$city . ", " . $province . ", " . $zip . ", " . $country;
```

Sending the server request.

```
        if(empty($streetNum_err) && empty($street_err) && empty($city_err) && empty($country_err) && empty($zip_err) && empty($province_err)){


            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_contacts SET address=:addrress WHERE contactid=:contactid";
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
                $stmt->bindParam(":address", $param_address);
                $stmt->bindParam(":contactid", $param_contactid);

                $param_address = $address;
                $param_contactid = $contactid;

                if($stmt->excute()){
                    header("location: firstlogin4.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }else{
                echo "something went wrong !!";
                header("location: error.php"); 
            }
            unset($stmt);
        }
        unset($pdo);
    }
?>
```

HTML - CSS - JavaScript

Here is my html, css and JavaScript, but I think the error is somewhere int the PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
    .wrapper{ width: 500px; padding: 20px; }
    label{font-weight: bold;}       

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="message">
        <h1>You have a tenant </h1>
        <h2>Let's get your mailing address so you don't miss out on whats going on with your Home Owner's Association</h2>
        <h3>We added 2 little steps ... Your almost there!!!</h3>
        <p> <?php echo $address ?> </P>
    </div>


    <div id="message2" class="wrapper">
        <div class="progress" style="width:350px">
            <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
        <h3 id="status">Phase 3 of 4</h3>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
            <label>Your home address:*</label>
            <p>*Other than units address</p>                    
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <label for="streetnumber">#</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetnumber" placeholder="1234" name="streetnumber">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="street">Street Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="Main St" name="street">
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unit">Address 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" name="unit">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label for="provincce">Province / State</label>
                    <select id="province" class="form-control" name="province">
                        <option selected="" disabled="" >--</option>
                        <option disabled="">--Canada--</option>
                        <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                        <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                        <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                        <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                        <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                        <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                        <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                        <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                        <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                        <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                        <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                        <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                        <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
                        <option disabled="">--USA--</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </div>                      
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zip">Postal Code/Zip</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" style="width: 33%" name="zip">
            </div>            
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="OK, next">
        </form>    
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        //When the page has loaded.
        $("#message").show();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#message").hide(); }, 2000);
        $("#message2").hide();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#message2").show(); }, 2000);
    </script>
    </body>


</html>
```

MySQL is not updating. So I guess there is something stopping the `$stmt->execute()`

Thank you a head of time for the help.

Comment: But you write `stmt->excute`  not `stmt->execute`...

Comment: There are issues with some of your code snippets. Please edit them. The 1st one seems cut in the middle. The 2nd and 3rd look like they need to be united, and so on. This has the makings of a good question but you need to improve it 1st. Good luck!

Comment: When you stare at something to longyou don<t seem to see anytthing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there's an error on the bindParams variable name on `UPDATE tbl_contacts SET address=:addrress WHERE contactid=:contactid`. You're writting ":addreess" and when it's time to bindParams you're setting it as ":address". Maybe if you fix this, your stmt->execute will work.
Second i think (just a guess) you should set the variables before you bind then.
Third, i think a debug will help you a lot in problems like this. Try installing xdebug and PHP-debug extension for VSCODE, put some breakpoint in these lines and start debbuging, it will be easier to find errors and get rid of them

Comment: Thanks their was a typo their also. I should take regular breaks.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Yes and installed the recomended plugins for vscode. I found out also that I had empty($_POST['country']) was stopping my code. I was not collecting the information so it was returning false. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes and installed the recomended plugins for vscode. I found out also that I had empty($_POST['country']) was stopping my code. I was not collecting the information so it was returning false. Thanks for your help.